# jquery cookies for different countries link

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to do cookie stuff in jquery 
but it not getting implemented can you guys fix my problem

**html code**

```
<a rel="en_CA" class="selectorCountries marginUnitedStates locale-link" href="http://www.teslamotors.com/en_CA">united states</a>
<a rel="en_US" class="selectorCountries marginSecondCountry locale-link" href="http://www.teslamotors.com/en_CA">canada</a>
<a rel="en_BE" class="selectorCountries marginCanadaFrench locale-link" href="http://www.teslamotors.com/en_BE">canada(french)</a>
```

i am providing my js code below

http://jsfiddle.net/SSMX4/76/

when i click the different country links in the pop up it should act similar to this site

http://www.teslamotors.com/it_CH

```
    $('.locale-link').click(function(){
        var desired_locale = $(this).attr('rel');
        createCookie('desired-locale',desired_locale,360);
        createCookie('buy_flow_locale',desired_locale,360);
        closeSelector('disappear');
    })

    $('#locale_pop a.close').click(function(){
        var show_blip_count = readCookie('show_blip_count');
        if (!show_blip_count) {
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        else if (show_blip_count < 3 ) {
            eraseCookie('show_blip_count');
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        $('#locale_pop').slideUp();
        return false;
    });


function checkCookie(){
        var cookie_locale = readCookie('desired-locale');
        var show_blip_count = readCookie('show_blip_count');
        var tesla_locale = 'en_US'; //default to US
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        // debug.log("path = " + path);
        var parsed_url = parseURL(window.location.href);
        var path_array = parsed_url.segments;
        var path_length = path_array.length
        var locale_path_index = -1;
        var locale_in_path = false;
        var locales = ['en_AT', 'en_AU', 'en_BE', 'en_CA',
                        'en_CH', 'de_DE', 'en_DK', 'en_GB',
                        'en_HK', 'en_EU', 'jp', 'nl_NL',
                        'en_US', 'it_IT', 'fr_FR', 'no_NO']
        // see if we are on a locale path
        $.each(locales, function(index, value){
            locale_path_index = $.inArray(value, path_array);
            if (locale_path_index != -1) {
                tesla_locale = value == 'jp' ? 'ja_JP':value;
                locale_in_path = true;
            } 
        });
        // debug.log('tesla_locale = ' + tesla_locale);
        cookie_locale = (cookie_locale == null || cookie_locale == 'null') ? false:cookie_locale;
        // Only do the js redirect on the static homepage.
        if ((path_length == 1) && (locale_in_path || path == '/')) {
            debug.log("path in redirect section = " + path);
            if (cookie_locale && (cookie_locale != tesla_locale)) {
                // debug.log('Redirecting to cookie_locale...');
                var path_base = '';
                switch (cookie_locale){
                    case 'en_US':
                        path_base = path_length > 1 ? path_base:'/';                    
                        break;
                    case 'ja_JP':
                        path_base = '/jp'
                        break;
                    default:
                        path_base = '/' + cookie_locale;
                }
                path_array = locale_in_path != -1 ? path_array.slice(locale_in_path):path_array;
                path_array.unshift(path_base);
                window.location.href = path_array.join('/');
            }
        }
        // only do the ajax call if we don't have a cookie
        if (!cookie_locale) {
            // debug.log('doing the cookie check for locale...')
            cookie_locale = 'null';
            var get_data = {cookie:cookie_locale, page:path, t_locale:tesla_locale};
            var query_country_string = parsed_url.query != '' ? parsed_url.query.split('='):false;
            var query_country = query_country_string ? (query_country_string.slice(0,1) == '?country' ? query_country_string.slice(-1):false):false;
            if (query_country) {
                get_data.query_country = query_country;
            }
            $.ajax({
                url:'/check_locale',
                data:get_data,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                            var ip_locale = data.locale;
                            var market = data.market;
                            var new_locale_link = $('#locale_pop #locale_link');
                            if (data.show_blip && show_blip_count < 3) {
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    $('#locale_msg').text(data.locale_msg);
                                    $('#locale_welcome').text(data.locale_welcome);
                                    new_locale_link[0].href = data.new_path;
                                    new_locale_link.text(data.locale_link);
                                    new_locale_link.attr('rel', data.locale);
                                    if (!new_locale_link.hasClass(data.locale)) {
                                        new_locale_link.addClass(data.locale);
                                    }
                                    $('#locale_pop').slideDown('slow', function(){
                                        var hide_blip = setTimeout(function(){
                                            $('#locale_pop').slideUp('slow', function(){
                                                        var show_blip_count = readCookie('show_blip_count');
                                                        if (!show_blip_count) {
                                                            createCookie('show_blip_count',1,360);
                                                        }
                                                        else if (show_blip_count < 3 ) {
                                                            var b_count = show_blip_count;
                                                            b_count ++; 
                                                            eraseCookie('show_blip_count');
                                                            createCookie('show_blip_count',b_count,360);
                                                        }
                                                });
                                            },10000);
                                        $('#locale_pop').hover(function(){
                                            clearTimeout(hide_blip);
                                            },function(){
                                                setTimeout(function(){$('#locale_pop').slideUp();},10000);
                                            });
                                    });
                                },1000);
                            }
                        }
            });
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any popups in your fiddle or the Tesla page.

Comment: @barma: thanks for your reply...without cookie i am posting in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SSMX4/77/ in tesla page you should moved down to the footer

Comment: All I see in the footer is "United States" in red.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for your reply when I click the united states you will see a pop up

Comment: Yes, I see it now. But you haven't said what you're trying to do and what it's doing wrong. Saying it should act similar to the other site doesn't mean anything.

Comment: when u click the pop up in tesla site...u see so many country links...when u click those link it leads to other country languages...this is done using cookies...i am trying to achieve it...

Comment: It's not using cookies to go to the other pages, they're just ordinary links. Cookies are probably used to remember the default page when the user goes to the main page instead of the page with the country code in it.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for your reply after clicking the country link in the popup when u try to go to the home page http://www.teslamotors.com/ it does not goes to this link but instead it goes to the country link this is what i am trying to implement....

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for your reply but when u click the link and then reach the home page it will redirect u to country link

Answer (score 0):

This will help you ALOT!

[jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

I use this all the time. Very simple to learn. Has all the necessary cookie functions built-in and allows you to use a tiny amount of code to create your cookies, delete them, make them expire, etc.

Let me know if you have any questions on how to use (although the DOCS have a decent amount of instruction).

Comment: thanks for your reply can you tell me whats wrong with this code http://jsfiddle.net/SSMX4/76/.....this code without cookie